# Merge child data frame columns to parent data frame with None values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a pandas data frame like this

##### EDITED

| Promotion ID | Month | Products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PID-1 | June | `Refer below for sample1` |
| PID-2 | July | `Refer below for sample2` |

sample1:
| Product Id|
|--|
|PROD1|
|PROD2|

sample2:
| Product Id|
|--|
|PROD1|
|PROD2|
|PROD3|

I would like to transform this data frame into the following

| Promotion ID | Month | Products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PID-1 | June | PROD1 |
|  |  | PROD2 |
| PID-2 | July | PROD 1 |
|  |  | PROD2 |
|  |  | PROD3 |

The empty spaces can just be `None` or `NA` values. Is there a way to do this in pandas without looping through the rows?

Comment: can you specify an actual example of the column products?

Comment: If is a data frame with one column called product ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `explode` to flatten your dataframe like this:

```py
#generating data
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['pid-1', 'June', '| Product Id|  |PROD1| |PROD2|'],
    ['pid-2', 'July', '| Product Id| |PROD1| |PROD2| |PROD3|']
], columns = ['Promotion ID', 'Month', 'Products'])

# extracting the product list
df['Products'] = df['Products']\
    .apply(lambda s: [x for x in re.split(' *\| *', s) if x != '' and x != 'Product Id'])
exploded_df = exploded_df = df.explode('Products', ignore_index=True)
```

At this point `df` and `exploded_df` look like this:

```
# df
  Promotion ID Month                Products
0        pid-1  June          [PROD1, PROD2]
1        pid-2  July  [PROD1, PROD2, PROD3]

# exploded_df
  Promotion ID Month Products
0        pid-1  June    PROD1
1        pid-1  June    PROD2
2        pid-2  July    PROD1
3        pid-2  July    PROD2
4        pid-2  July   PROD3
```

I would stop there. IMHO only keeping the values of `Month` and `Promotion ID` for the first rows will only make your like harder. Yet, since you ask you could use `rank` and `loc` to assign `None` to all the rows that are not the first of their groups:

```py
# rank needs a numeric column
exploded_df['index'] = exploded_df.index
# using rank to create a filter on rows that are not the first of their group
filter = exploded_df\
    .groupby(['Promotion ID'])['index']\
    .rank('dense').apply(lambda x: x > 1)
# getting rid of the index column
exploded_df = exploded_df.drop('index', axis=1)
# and voila
exploded_df.loc[filter, ['Month', 'Promotion ID']] = None
```

The result:

```
  Promotion ID Month Products
0         None  None    PROD1
1        pid-1  June    PROD2
2         None  None    PROD1
3        pid-2  July    PROD2
4        pid-2  July   PROD3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I think its on the same lines as what I'm looking for but I think I confused you with the way my question was formed.. I edited it to make it a little bit clearer. Products actually holds a nested data frame.

Comment: You just need to change the way to Split the data in the apply function. Something like `[x for x in re.split(' *\| *', s) if x != '' and x != 'Product Id']`

Comment: I edited the answer. If that's still not what you want, try providing a way to generate a minimal example

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Comment: Your answer is close to the answer I want.. and the only one I got :)

Comment: Do you need help? I tried to design something with the input data you gave but it was hard to interpret. A standard format like CSV or the code to genarate the sample would help a lot :)